# Find the New Position of Vertices Given a Rotation Matrix

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, rotational-matrices

I have two triangles facing in arbitrary directions. I have the forward vector for both triangles, and I want to align each of the forward vectors to face the same direction. I only have the ability to do rotations about the world x, y and z axis (The software API I am using is very limited).

So, let A = forward vector of the first triangle, and B = forward vector of the second triangle.
I am able to find the Rotation Matrix using this equation:

```
v = B X A
s = ||v||
c = A dot B

vx = skew-symmetric cross-product matrix of v

R = I + [vx] + [vx]^2 * (1-c)/s^2
```

I am able to find R.

I am not sure how to use R so that I can move the vertices of triangle B such that the triangle B and triangle A are facing in the same direction.

Picture for Reference:

[image]

Thank you all in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use normalized vector v as an axis and the angle T between A and B to compute a rotation matrix (right-hand rule) from an axis-angle in the following way:

```
| cosT + x*x*(1 - cosT)      y*x*(1 - cosT) + z*sinT    z*x*(1 - cosT) - y*sinT |
| x*y*(1 - cosT) - z*sinT    cosT + y*y*(1 - cosT)      z*y*(1 - cosT) + x*sinT |
| x*z*(1 - cosT) + y*sinT    y*z*(1 - cosT) - x*sinT    cosT + z*z*(1 - cosT)   |
```

x, y, z values refers to normalized v coordinates.

Now, you apply this matrix to each vertex in B.

PS: This matrix is in column-major order, you might want to transpose it.

Comment: There is one last thing I forgot to mention (I updated the post with it). I only have the ability to do world rotations (x, y, z axis only). I can't apply a rotation around a vector. The software I am using is very limited.

Comment: Actually this matrix is a composition of rotations in x, y and z axis (not necessarily in this order).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this more easily by calculating the angle [between to forward vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) first:

```
theta = arccos(dot(A, B)/(length(A)*length(B)))
```

This gives you the angle by which you want to rotate your triangle. Then you can put this angle in the [2D rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) and use it to calculate each vertex's new position:

```
vector2 newPos = R*oldPos, Where R is the rotation matrix
```

Comment: That would work, assuming I am in a 2D plane. I have to account for the Z direction as well.